# Как поставить слово(Английское) в начальную форму с помощью NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Как поставить слово (aнглийское) в начальную форму с помощью nltk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763393/how-to-get-the-infinitive-form-of-the-verb-using-nltk-pos-tagging)

```
>>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('is', 'v')
'be'
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('provided', 'v')
'provide'
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('using', 'v')
'use'
```